# Does Sharepoint work without Office 365

Tags: site-usage

Can you use SharePoint without having Office 365?  Thanks!

Comment: is sharepoint online referring to file server?
how do i install sharepoint online? do i need to install sharepoint 2016/2019 server?

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint online is part of the O365 services, you can subscribe for this service alone, you don't need to subscribe for Lync or Exchange. That's in case you are looking to use SharePoint Online.

If you want to install SharePoint on-premises, so for sure it doesn't need O365.

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 is complete suit of products which include Office, Exchange, Lync, Yammer, AD, Sharepoint. [Check this](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-enterprise-e4-business-software)

If you want to use only SharePoint, then you need to buy the SharePoint online plan...[Select one plan which fit your needs](https://products.office.com/en-us/SharePoint/compare-sharepoint-plans)

Now another Option is, You can install the SharePoint on prem. That's mean you need to install the SharePoint either free version(SharePoint Foundation) or you have to buy the SharePoint Server license, you need the Server Hardware, as well as SQL Server & Windows Server OS license as well.

Comment: In the circumstance, that you want to use an on-premise installation of SharePoint (and have the hardware to support the on-premise environment)... (See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx). I would recommend using the AutoSPInstaller (http://autospinstaller.codeplex.com/) available on CodePlex. I've used it multiple times to set up server farms. It will work for both SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013.